# On Equivalence of "gen-CONF" problem and "DH-exp-inv" problem

Tags: reductions

Let $g$ be a generator of a group of prime order $p$; $a,b ∈_R Z_p^+$

Consider an Algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ which on input $g,g^a,g^{ab}$ outputs $g^{br},r$, for some non zero $r ∈ Z_p$

And an algorithm $\mathcal{B}$ which on the same inputs, $g,g^a,g^{ab}$, outputs $a^{-1}$

Can I claim the algorithms $\mathcal{A} \equiv \mathcal{B}$?

While it's trivial to construct $\mathcal{A}$ using $\mathcal{B}$, can we also construct a $\mathcal{B}$ using $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: No, since $\mathcal{A}$ could just output $\:g^0,p\;$. $\;\;\;$ I think that "$g$ is a" should be replaced with "$g$ be a" and that "non zero $r$" should be replaced with $\;$ "non-zero $\: r\in Z_p \;$". $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer thanks, one of the best things I like about you is your love for mathematical rigor :)

Comment: $g$ can't be a generator of order $p$ if $g \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$.  Perhaps you mean $g$ is a generator of prime order $q$, and $r \in \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$?